# OnitemClick on the this fragment takes 2-3 seconds to call a intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

onItemClick of the fragment calls a intent to another Activity.

onItemClick takes long time 2-3 secs.  That after onitemclick its stays for approx 2-3 on the current clicked screen and then moves to the activity.

and moreover repeated moveing to activity and coming back pressing the back button for like 20 times causes the crash as well without logs 
Have tried to debug for last 2 days.

No luck Please Please Please HELP.

Please find the code below
 **BatchListActivity.java**

/**
 * Created by E0000099 on 08-09-2015.
 */

```
  public class  BatchListActivity extends BaseActivity {
        private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private String[] tabNames = {"List", "Location"};
        private ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mAssetTaskCollectionModelList;
        private BatchListViewPagerAdapter mBatchListViewAdapter;
        private String mBatchNumber = null;
        public static  ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList = new ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel>();
        private CustomProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            displayActionBar();

            mBatchNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("Batch Number");

            if(mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList.size() == 0) {
                mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList.size();
            }
            mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList =   MyListActivity.batchNumberListHashMap.get(mBatchNumber);

            setActionBarTitle("Batch Number " + mBatchNumber);
            tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_batch_list);
            tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_batch_list);
            mBatchListViewAdapter = new BatchListViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mBatchListViewAdapter);

            tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
            tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                @Override
                public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
                }
            });
          }


        @Override
        protected int getLayoutResource() {
            return R.layout.activity_batch_list;
        }
    }

    **BatchListFragment**

    public class BatchListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        private ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mAssetTaskCollectionBatchList = new ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel>();
        private ListView mBatchNumberListView;
        private EditText SearchEt;
        private BatchListAdapter mBatchListAdapter;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_batch_list, container, false);
            SearchEt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_et);
            mBatchNumberListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.batch_list);
            new LoadListObjectsTask(getActivity()).execute();
            return view;
        }




        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
            // getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Common.isAssetManuallyVerified = true;
                    AssetTaskCollectionModel assetTaskCollectionModelObj = (AssetTaskCollectionModel) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateStatusActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("AssetDataObj", assetTaskCollectionModelObj);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addasset_menu, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_scan:
                    checkIfAssetsArePresent();
                    return true;
                case android.R.id.home:
                    getActivity().finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void checkIfAssetsArePresent() {

            Common.scanSearchFromTheList = true;
            Common.scanFromAddAsset = false;

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(DefaultSettingsActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean(DefaultSettingsActivity.CAMERA, true) &&
                    sharedpreferences.getBoolean(DefaultSettingsActivity.PHER, true)) {
                ScanPopupDialog scanPopupDialog = new ScanPopupDialog(getActivity());
                scanPopupDialog.show();
            } else if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean(DefaultSettingsActivity.PHER, true)) {

                CustomAlertDialog alertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Info", "No Peripheral connected", "Ok", new CustomAlertDialog2Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onButtonClick3() {
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            } else if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean(DefaultSettingsActivity.CAMERA, true)) {
                Intent intentToScan = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentToScan);
            }
        }
       private class LoadListObjectsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, List<AssetTaskCollectionModel>, Void> {

            private Context mContext;

            private LoadListObjectsTask(Context context){
                this.mContext = context;
            }


            @Override
            public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                mBatchListAdapter = new BatchListAdapter(mContext, BatchListActivity.mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList);
                SearchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)) {
                            mBatchListAdapter.clearFilter();
                        } else mBatchListAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }
                });
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                mBatchNumberListView.setAdapter(mBatchListAdapter);


            }
        }
    }
```

**UpdateStatusActivty.java**

```
public class UpdateStatusActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView fDescriptionValue, fAssetClassValue, fCompanyCodeValue, fSerialValue, fAssetValue, fLastinventoryValue,
            fCapitializedValue, fCostCenterValue, fPlantValue, fLocationValue, fCurrentLocationValue, fSubdescription;

    private AssetTaskCollectionModel mAssetModel;
    private Button fTagAssetBtn;
    private String mAddress;
    private ImageView fLocationArrow;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mAssetModel = (AssetTaskCollectionModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AssetDataObj");
        displayActionBar();
        setActionBarTitle("Asset Data");
        initializeViews();
       setData();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        fTagAssetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addassetButton);
        fTagAssetBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        fDescriptionValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_value);
        fAssetClassValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assetclass_value);
        fCompanyCodeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companycode_value);
        fSerialValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serial_value);
        fAssetValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asset_value);
        fLastinventoryValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastinventory_value);
        fCapitializedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capitialized_value);
        fCostCenterValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.costcenter_value);
        fPlantValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plant_value);
        fLocationValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_value);
        fCurrentLocationValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.geolocation_value);
        //description
        fSubdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subdescription);
        fLocationArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.locationArrow);
        fLocationArrow.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    private void setData()
    {
        fTagAssetBtn.setText("Update Status");
        fSubdescription.setText(mAssetModel.getANLN1());
        fDescriptionValue.setText(mAssetModel.getTXT50());
        fAssetClassValue.setText(mAssetModel.getANLKL());
        fCompanyCodeValue.setText(mAssetModel.getBUKRS());
        //serial number
        fSerialValue.setText(mAssetModel.getSERNR());
        //tag number
        fAssetValue.setText(mAssetModel.getINVNR());
        fLastinventoryValue.setText(mAssetModel.getIVDAT());
        fCapitializedValue.setText("");
        fCostCenterValue.setText(mAssetModel.getKOSTL() + "\n");
        fPlantValue.setText(mAssetModel.getWERKS() + "\n" + mAssetModel.getWERKSDESCRIPTION());
        fLocationValue.setText(mAssetModel.getSTORT());
        fCurrentLocationValue.setOnClickListener(this);
        GPSService mGPSService = new GPSService(this);
        mGPSService.getLocation();
        if (!mGPSService.isLocationAvailable) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your location is not available, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mAddress = mGPSService.getLocationAddress();
            fCurrentLocationValue.setText(mAddress.substring(0, 12) + "...");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_assetdata;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addassetButton:
                if (Common.isAssetManuallyVerified == true) {

                    Intent mIntentToUpdateStatus = new Intent(UpdateStatusActivity.this, UpdateStatusSubmitActivity.class);
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("BUKRS", fCompanyCodeValue.getText());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("ANLN1", fSubdescription.getText());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("ANLN2", mAssetModel.getANLN2());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("BATCHNUMBER", mAssetModel.getBATCHNUMBER());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("COMPLETIONSTATUS", mAssetModel.getCOMPLETIONSTATUS());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("LVTNR", mAssetModel.getLVTNR());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("LETXT", mAssetModel.getLETXT());
                    startActivity(mIntentToUpdateStatus);
                } else {
                    Intent mIntentToUpdateStatus = new Intent(UpdateStatusActivity.this, UpdateStatusBarcodeSubmitActivity.class);
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("BUKRS", fCompanyCodeValue.getText());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("ANLN1", fSubdescription.getText());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("ANLN2", mAssetModel.getANLN2());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("BATCHNUMBER", mAssetModel.getBATCHNUMBER());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("COMPLETIONSTATUS", mAssetModel.getCOMPLETIONSTATUS());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("LVTNR", mAssetModel.getLVTNR().toString());
                    mIntentToUpdateStatus.putExtra("LETXT", mAssetModel.getLETXT().toString());
                    startActivity(mIntentToUpdateStatus);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.geolocation_value:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayLocationMap.class);
                intent.putExtra("TAG", mAddress);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.locationArrow:
                Intent intentToLocation = new Intent(this, DisplayLocationMap.class);
                intentToLocation.putExtra("TAG", mAddress);
                startActivity(intentToLocation);
                break;
        }
```

}

```
}
```

**BatchListAdapter.java**

```
public class BatchListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  Filterable {
    protected static final String TAG = "BatchListAdapter.java";
    public Context context;
    private ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList  ;
    private int mBacgroundColor;
    private ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mFiltereditemsList;
    /**
     * Contructor to pass the Reference
     *
     * @parama
     */

    public BatchListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList) {
        this.context = context;
        mFiltereditemsList = mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList ;
        this.mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList = mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList;
    }

    public void clearFilter() {
        mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList = mFiltereditemsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AssetTaskCollectionModel getItem(int i) {
        return mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList.get(i);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView  fAssetNoLabel, fAssetNoValue, fDescriptionLabel, fDescriptionValue,
                fTagNoLabel,fTagNoValue,  fSerialNoLabel,  fSerialNoValue;
        RelativeLayout fListBackground;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.batch_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder. fListBackground = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main);
            holder. fAssetNoLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.asset_no_label);
            holder. fAssetNoValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.asset_no_value);
            holder. fDescriptionLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_label);
            holder. fDescriptionValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_value);
            holder. fTagNoLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag_no_label);
            holder. fTagNoValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag_no_value);
            holder.  fSerialNoLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial_no_label);
            holder. fSerialNoValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial_no_value);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        AssetTaskCollectionModel mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj =   getItem(position);
        holder. fListBackground.setBackgroundColor( getListBackGroundColor(mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj));
        holder. fAssetNoLabel.setText("Asset No: ");
        holder. fDescriptionLabel.setText("Description: ");
        holder. fTagNoLabel.setText("Tag No: ");
        holder. fSerialNoLabel.setText("Serial No: ");
        holder. fAssetNoValue.setText(mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj.getANLN1());
        holder. fDescriptionValue.setText(mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj.getTXT50());
        holder. fTagNoValue.setText(mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj.getINVNR());
        holder. fSerialNoValue.setText(mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj.getSERNR());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mAssetTaskCollectionBatchAssetList = (ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (!(constraint.toString().isEmpty())) {
                    ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<AssetTaskCollectionModel>();
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mFiltereditemsList.size(); i++) {
                        if (
                                mFiltereditemsList.get(i).getANLN1().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
                                        mFiltereditemsList.get(i).getTXT50().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
                                        mFiltereditemsList.get(i).getINVNR().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) ||
                                        mFiltereditemsList.get(i).getSERNR().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)
                                ) {
                            filteredList.add(mFiltereditemsList.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = filteredList.size();
                    results.values = filteredList;
                    return results;
                } else {
                    results.count = mFiltereditemsList.size();
                    results.values = mFiltereditemsList;
                    return results;
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public int getListBackGroundColor( AssetTaskCollectionModel mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj ) {
        if (!mAssetTaskCollectionModelObj.getCOMPLETIONSTATUS().equalsIgnoreCase("00")) {
            mBacgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_view_green);
        } else {
            mBacgroundColor =context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_view_transperent);
        }
        return mBacgroundColor;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you do too much work in `UpdateStatusActivity`

Comment: have added UpdateStatusActivity.java to the above question and also its staying on the clicked fragment for a while

Comment: Please help guys ....I am getting mad with the issues

Comment: So, what is `GPSService `? may `getLocation()` method block main thread?

Comment: I have tried commenting it and issue still persist

Comment: try to comment `SearchEt.addTextChangedListener` or take a look at `BatchListAdapter` is there any wrong opration?

Comment: Hey Rainish,I have added the BatchListAdapter as well

Comment: Please answer the question  guys ... I getting mad debugging the issue

Comment: If I were you, I first detect which piece of code cause the problem, so you can move the code under `onItemClick` to another Activity and excute, if `UpdateStatusActivity` is still slowly open, maybe there's something wrong in `UpdateStatusActivity`.